# React Native: Cannot see the change after running command "npm run android" on Mac Terminal

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[image]

Hi, I am using Android Studio to run React Native. However, I am not able to see the change after running command "npm run android" inside the folder that contains all the files (App.js). I am stuck with this instruction screen and don't know how to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: Try with `react-native run-android` command in terminal.

Comment: It says command not found :(

Comment: in which directory you try to execute this command? is it android directory? or react native project directory?

Comment: react native project directory.

Comment: are you try to shake your device and reload data ?

Comment: How do I shake it?

Comment: Oops My mistake. Check this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/247-react-native-tutorial-building-android-apps-with-javascript

Comment: Is the tutorial helps?

Comment: @YongJunJung try with terminal. If command not found please make sure react native cli is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run: npm install -g react-native-cli

then , run : react-native run-android